# jquery supports function pageload() and $().ready()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Does jquery support both function pageload() and $().ready() ?

Or is pageload() for ajax.net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only supports $().ready()

Answer (score 2):

JQuery does not have a pageload function.

Answer (score 1):

http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/