# $(document).ready(function() does not work perfectly in Content Pages / Telerik Controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, null, document-ready

The pages on my project are base on master and content pages...

I want to do something with javascript(rather than jquery) in one of content pages after
**ALL OF MASTER AND CONTENT ELEMENTS ARE LOADED COMPLETELY**.(for example set focus on a RadComboBox Control)

For doing that I used the below code :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script src="../JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        onload = onloadOfDocument;

        function onloadOfDocument() {

            var combo = $find("<%= RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID %>");
            alert(combo);
            var comboInput = combo.get_inputDomElement();
            comboInput.focus();
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

But `alert(combo);` always returns null.(the `$find` code is for telerik controls and the upper codes about telerik controls are completely true)

To solve this `null` problem I test the ways shown below:

1-
I Removed all of controls from master and content page except RadComboBox Control and null problem disappeared , so i derived the null peoblem is about all of elements of master and content page have not been loaded when

`$find("<%= RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID %>");`

is fired.

2-
so i used

`$(document).ready(function() { my codes });`

instead of

`onload = onloadOfDocument;`

but problem not solved - i do not know why!!!

3-
at last i test the below code and it works perfectly :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

<script src="../JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    //onload = onloadOfDocument;
      document.onkeyup = onkeyupOfDocument;

    function onkeyupOfDocument() {

        var combo = $find("<%= RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID %>");
        alert(combo);
        var comboInput = combo.get_inputDomElement();
        comboInput.focus();
    }

</script>
```

What function of document should i use for doing some javascript codes **after all Of MASTER AND CONTENT ELEMENTS are loaded completely**?

Thanks in future advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760762/jquery-supports-function-pageload-and-ready/2469913#2469913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below link solved my problem :
[$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!](http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

my answer -> using pageLoad() instead of $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
var combo=$("#<%= RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID %>")[0];
```

?

(Assuming that `RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID` resolves to the id attribute of an element in the DOM)

Comment: That's what I would've thought the issue is too.
The easiest way to check if $(document).ready(function(){ }); is working is to add an alert... and then to add the code that you want run in there.

It gives a simple and clean way to determine whether jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: var combo=$("#<%= RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID %>")[0];
-> this syntax is incorrect...
=============
i test $(document).ready(function(){ }); with alert and alert works fine - but $find still returns null...

Comment: Umm. Why is it incorrect? What are you trying to do? Get the element with ID RadcbPersonelCompleteNameInvwNoskhehEdit.ClientID, or did I misunderstand? I've never seen $find before.

Comment: the syntax of upper codes (about telerik controls) at my question are true -> refer to #3th test...
it seems problem is about $(document).ready(function(){ }); but i test it with an alert and alert works fine - i do not know what is going on about document.ready!